# Android: Is it possible to set View height proportional to the View width?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to set the View width into the screen width and the View height into 0.8 * View width. Is it possible to achieve this from the XML Layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it could easily be done by creating a custom subclass of the view you want and overriding onMeasure to return those sizes.